# Spring boot 2.2.2 fail with Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.log.LogMessage

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some problem with spring boot 2.2.2. It failed with error `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.log.LogMessage`

[image]

when some libs not found in classpath.
Main reason than LogMessage not found beacuse spring devtool 2.2.2 have dependence spring core 5.1.2

[image]
[image]

In this version no class founds LogMessage you can see in screenshots. This class is added only 5.2.0. Is it issue? [LogMessage.class in 5.2.4](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/log/LogMessage.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Spring boot 2.2.5 and it finds the LogMessage class just fine. Make sure you have all the Spring Boot files downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Cached version, update maven index fix problem. Now can close question!

Comment: You can delete the question if it is no longer reproducable.