# Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain API endpoint

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement oauth2 on some endpoints within my API. here is my config class:

```java
@Configuration
@Order(102)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").permitAll()
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/endpoint1").hasAuthority("SCOPE_READ")
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").hasAuthority("SCOPE_WRITE")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
```

There are other config files within my project hence I added the order annotation but I keep receiving the  Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain error.

Here are the related dependencies in my `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried explicitly using the last version (5.5.3) of spring security web but I'm still receiving the error. Here's the full stack trace:

```
"timestamp":"2021-11-02T15:16:59.774Z","message":"Application run failed","logger":"o.s.b.SpringApplication","thread":"restartedMain","level":"ERROR","stack_trace":"<#20be4d11> o.s.b.f.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogMessage\r\n\tat o.s.b.f.s.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)\r\n\tat o.s.b.f.s.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)\r\n\tat o.s.b.f.s.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)\r\n\tat o.s.b.f.s.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
```

This is my first time working with the Spring security features and would like more insight on resolving this issue.

Comment: maybe that question can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60606498/spring-boot-2-2-2-fail-with-caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-spr

Comment: You can improve stack trace format that is not readable.

Comment: my apologies I have edited the stack trace for clarity

Comment: Try with removing Order(102)

Comment: I tried that initially but then i got an error saying that the order of 100 had to be unique hence why I annotated this class with and order of 102